# upload file not working. May be some permissions issue

Tags: php, apache

I'm wondering from so long, file upload section doesn't work. I google as much to solve this issue and I found there may be an issue with file permission on the upload directory but I couldn't understand how to implement the same with my code. follwing is the code.

```
                 $tech_file_path = FCPATH . "uploads/" .  $tech_file_name ;
                 $sci_file_path = FCPATH . "uploads/" .  $sci_file_name ;

                 $tech_just_pdf_info = exec("pdfinfo " . $tech_file_path) ;
                 $tech_just_pdf_info = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $tech_just_pdf_info);
                 $tech_pdf_version_array = explode(":",$tech_just_pdf_info) ;
                 $tech_pdf_version = 1.6;
                 //$tech_pdf_version = $tech_pdf_version_array[1];


                 $sci_just_pdf_info = exec("pdfinfo " . $sci_file_path) ;
                 $sci_just_pdf_info = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $sci_just_pdf_info);
                 $sci_pdf_version_array = explode(":",$sci_just_pdf_info) ;
                 $sci_pdf_version = 1.6;
                 //$sci_pdf_version = $sci_pdf_version_array[1];


                 if($tech_pdf_version > 1.4)
                 {
                     // Convert PDF version to 1.4

                     shell_exec("mv " . $tech_file_path. " " . FCPATH . "uploads/temp.pdf");
                     $command1 = "/usr/bin/gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -o "  . $tech_file_path . " " .  FCPATH . "uploads/temp.pdf" ;

                     $pdf_cmd_result1 = shell_exec($command1) ;

                 }

                 if($sci_pdf_version > 1.4)
                 {
                     shell_exec("mv " . $sci_file_path. " " . FCPATH . "uploads/temp.pdf");
                     $command2 = "/usr/bin/gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -o " . $sci_file_path . " " .  FCPATH . "uploads/temp.pdf" ;

                     $pdf_cmd_result2 = shell_exec($command2) ;
                 }
```

file path and size etc

```
 {
    // attachemets tech and scientific_justification
      $config['upload_path']          = '../hctopses/uploads/';           
      $config['allowed_types']        = 'pdf';
      $config['max_size']             = 5120; // max size in KB
      $config['file_name']            = "tech_just" .  $this->session->userdata('proposal_id') . ".pdf";
      $config['overwrite']            = TRUE ;


      $this->load->library('upload', $config);

      $err_msg = "" ;
      $success_msg = "" ;

      if (isset($_FILES['tech_justification']) && is_uploaded_file($_FILES['tech_justification']['tmp_name']))
      {
        $config['file_name']  = "tech_just" .  $this->session->userdata('proposal_id') . ".pdf";  /////

          $this->upload->initialize($config);  ///////
          if( ! $this->upload->do_upload('tech_justification'))
          {
                  $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                  $err_msg = "<b> Error </b> uploading Tech Just : " . implode($error, " ");
                  //$this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
          }
          else
          {
                  //$data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
                  //echo implode($this->upload->data(), " ");
                  $success_msg =  "<b>Success 1 :</b> Tech Just File Uploaded Successfully." ;
                  //$this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
          }
      }else{
          $success_msg =  "<b>Success 1 :</b> Tech Just File kept as it is Successfully." ;
      }


      if (isset($_FILES['sci_justification']) && is_uploaded_file($_FILES['sci_justification']['tmp_name']))
      {
          $config['file_name']  = "sci_just" .  $this->session->userdata('proposal_id') . ".pdf";

          $this->upload->initialize($config);
          if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('sci_justification'))
          {
                  $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                  $err_msg = $err_msg . "\n <b> Error </b>uploading Sci Just : " . implode($error, " ");
                  //$this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
          }
          else
          {
                  //$data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
                  //echo implode($this->upload->data(), " ");
                  $success_msg =  $success_msg . "\n <b>Success 2 :</b> Sci Just File Uploaded Successfully." ;
                  //$this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
          }
      }else{
          $success_msg =  $success_msg . "\n <b>Success 2 :</b> Sci Just File Kept as it is Successfully." ;
      }


        if($err_msg != "")
        {
            echo $err_msg ;
        }else{
            echo $success_msg ;
        }

     //echo "Save step five Called" ;
}
```

Thank in advance..

Answer (score 0):

From the first part of your code, the variable $sci_pdf_version doesn't get updated so the two following if statements will both be run everytime.

```
             $sci_pdf_version = 1.6;
             //$sci_pdf_version = $sci_pdf_version_array[1];


             if($tech_pdf_version > 1.4)
             {
                 // Convert PDF version to 1.4

                 shell_exec("mv " . $tech_file_path. " " . FCPATH . "uploads/temp.pdf");
                 $command1 = "/usr/bin/gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -o "  . $tech_file_path . " " .  FCPATH . "uploads/temp.pdf" ;

                 $pdf_cmd_result1 = shell_exec($command1) ;

             }

             if($sci_pdf_version > 1.4)
             {
                 shell_exec("mv " . $sci_file_path. " " . FCPATH . "uploads/temp.pdf");
                 $command2 = "/usr/bin/gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -o " . $sci_file_path . " " .  FCPATH . "uploads/temp.pdf" ;

                 $pdf_cmd_result2 = shell_exec($command2) ;
             }
```

In respect to the upload issue, can you provide any error messages you receive in order for others to better help.

You can check you httpd logs for info if nothing is being shown on your browser or set the following at the top of your php script:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
```

This will override your settings in php.ini to force errors to be shown.

Also, if you have SSH access to your server, please run the following in your "FCCPATH":

```
ls -alhR
```

This will list everything in the directory recursively so you only need to show the output for "uploads" and its contents if your worried about showing other files you have in the directory.

This will show the file and folder permissions so we can see what your current file permissions are set to to further assist you.

Comment: Thanks for your consern.. apache_ error log says [Thu May 24 14:55:29 2018] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration: C:/wamp/www...............